# Updating Flask code when Swagger file is updated

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I have been troubles finding a good workflow for the api development with Flask and Swagger.

Let's say we created a swagger (.yml) file, based on which Flask files created and now everything works as expected.

However, we want to extend swagger file or maybe modify properties of the existing urls.

When we do that, and generate new Flask code, we have empty functions. Now, one might just copy paste stuff around, but are there any better solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: For generating Flask code, are you using Swagger Codegen (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)?

Comment: yeah, but I am open to exploring different possibilities as well

Comment: Please start a discussion via github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the Swagger Codegen community can join the discussion.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45680372/1366989) for an alternate approach.